# Authorization errors after restoring a database from a backup

Tags: db2, authorization, database-restore, db2-luw

I want to export the different privileges in a DB2 9.7 database as DDL.

I found the following in the documentation:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.8.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.gui.doc/doc/t0021930.html

> Authorization statements: Generates SQL authorization (GRANT) statements for the database objects.

When I try to issue the command

```
db2look -d DatabaseName -u user
```

I get the following error:

```
SQL0552N  "USER1" does not have the privilege to perform operation 
"BIND".  SQLSTATE=42502
```

When I try to give DBADM to the user1, I get the following error:

```
db2 "GRANT DBADM ON DATABASE TO USER USER1"

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a valid Command Line Processor command.
During SQL processing it returned:
SQL4707N  Workload "SYSDEFAULTUSERWORKLOAD" cannot service the request
because the workload is not allowed to access the database or is disabled.
Reason code: ""  SQLSTATE=5U020
```

I face this problem after restoring the database from a backup.

Comment: By "importing the database from a dump" do you actually mean restoring it from a backup? If so, is the instance owner on the server where the backup was taken different from the one where you did a restore?

Comment: Yes, I modified the question.

Comment: No it is the same. I think this is related though:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21568865
I am trying it at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21568865 
did the trick:

```
db2set DB2_RESTORE_GRANT_ADMIN_AUTHORITIES=ON
```

Allows the instance user to execute the command.